# Multiple preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have many strings that all start with @and a pseudo and I want to change these pseudo via regex to the real name. 
I haven't many pseudo (maybe 5 to 10) so I can go with a simple regex like:

```
        $find = array('@alex', '@donald');
        $replace = array('Alex A.', 'Donald B.' );
        $result= preg_replace($find, $replace, $feed->itemTitle);
```

My problem is that I already have a pre_replace on these string, that removes the link. So far this is my regex:

```
<?php echo preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?).....@',' ',$feed->itemTitle); ?>
```

I can't come up with a solution that will mix the two regex. (regex is something I am not confortable with).

Comment: Don't try to mix them. Do them in two `preg_replace()` statements.

Comment: Thanks Amal! So how should I proceed ?

Comment: If you're doing multiple string replaces, just use `str_replace()` with arrays as the search and replace parameters. Take a look at the [`str_replace()` docs](http://php.net/str-replace) for examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have already a `preg_replace` for the links isn't a problem, don't bother about that.

If you want you can build a giant pattern with capture groups to be used with `preg_replace_callback` that allows the callback function to choose which is the replacement string to return according to the capture group number. However, this isn't the good way.

Since, you want to replace fixed strings *(`@alex`, `@donald` are fixed strings)* the best and fastest way is to use `strtr` *(even if you parse the string a second time)*:

```
$trans = array('@alex'   => 'Alex A.',
               '@donald' => 'Donald B.');

$result = strtr($feed->itemTitle, $trans);
```